# Как ввести капчу от google при запросе в консольном приложении?

Tags: node.js, recaptcha, captcha, google-recaptcha

При попытке выдать ответ по запросу, срабатывает гугл капча. Как можно её ввести, для продолжения выполняемого кода? Вывод консоли:[image: Вот, что показывает консоль.]

Comment: Ну, Гугл использует капчу как раз для того, чтобы не дать работать подобным консольным приложениям (ибо нарушение ToS, все дела). Поэтому, даже если какое-то временный костыль и найдется, то Гугл рано или поздно это просечёт, и либо поменяет свою логику проверки, либо совсем забанит Ваш IP.